# Receiving validation data from the validation_split within model training with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem. I used the `validation_split` to split my data and I did get an output of accuarcy and loss after each epoch.

However, I would like to visualize a ROC curve based on the validation data. Is there a possibility to get this validation data and to create the ROC curve on it?

```py
loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0009)
metrics = ["accuracy"]

model_lstm.compile(loss=loss ,optimizer = optim, metrics=metrics)

history = model_lstm.fit(train_X,train_y,batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_split=0.15, callbacks=CALLBACKS)

# What I want
X_val, y_val = history.validation_data
y_true = model.predict(X_val)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the code -> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/HEAD/keras/engine/training.py#L1304
it's not possible to get back the validation data to run your ROC curve using validation_split.

However you can split the dataset before between train, test and validation and pass the validation to the fit function with the paramater validation_data.